# NSDateFormatter dateFromString with format 'hh:mm a' return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i came across a problem in my iPhone application.

in my app i converte time string to date like that

```
NSString *time = @"01:30 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:time];
```

and for some reason always `date` is nil after `[dateFormat dateFromString:time]`.

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: No it's working fine  output:2000-01-01 08:00:00 +0000

Comment: what exactly you need to display?

Comment: i have couple strings of times that are in format hh:mm a and i need to compare between them, so i want to convert them to NSDate for the compare

Comment: Is your locale set to English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your device language is other then English. In that case you need to set the date formatter Locale. Try this code.

```
NSString *time = @"01:30 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Comment: Output is not in required format as per asked by person (console output : 2000-01-01 08:00:00 +0000) and same as already provide in above comments

Comment: @user3414609 - I dont see how your output changed with locale use. As I just ran your code with and without locale output is same.

Comment: @nikhil84 because your locale is already in english if you try changing your device in some other language then you will get Nil.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
NSString *time = @"01:30 pm";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
dateFormat.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:time];

NSLog(@"date %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *dats1 = @"01:30:00 PM";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [dateFormatter1 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dats1];
    NSLog(@"date : %@", date);

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```